# Enabling sound in xine on certain alsa device (0.3 for HDMI)?

Tags: video, audio, alsa

I'd like xine v0.99.6 to output my sound through alsa device 0.3 (my HDMI output). This is, as always :), Ubuntu 11.04 on a small Atom box with the NVIDIA ION chipset, just in case anyone would like to know.

ALSA is configured and working,

```
mplayer -ao alsa:device=hw=0.3 -vo xv some-video.mkv
```

plays fine (audio and video). The reason I do not stay with mplayer is that mplayer switches back to the desktop between videos, which is not wanted in this case.

My commandline for starting up xine so far is

```
xine --video-driver xv -audio-driver alsa --auto-play fh --fullscreen --hide-gui --no-gui --no-mouse --no-logo --no-splash --network
```

from whereon I control the playback of different videos using a ruby script (through the network connection on port 6789).

Any ideas would help tremendously,

thanks in advance,

```
Christian.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally got it myself ;)

Edit `/etc/asoundrc` to add a new, virtual device `hdmi` as so (I had to `reboot` after this step, you might be smarter and be able to somehow re-start `ALSA`):

```
pcm.!hdmi {
    type hw
    card 0
    device 3
}

ctl.!hdmi {
    type hw           
    card 0
    device 3
}
```

Then edit `.xine/config` to include these lines (or alter your entries if they already exist); this will tell `xine`to using the new "named device" `hdmi` for it's sound output:

```
audio.device.alsa_default_device:hdmi
audio.device.alsa_front_device:hdmi
```

Voilà, done. Remember this only works if your HDMI output is actually enabled, I had to use `alsamixer` to enable my SPDIF output first. Use my `mplayer`-line from above to test your output first (having no xine running, it blocks `ALSA`).